# How to add basic authorization header by passing the secret using reqwest?

Tags: rust, header, reqwest

I'm using `reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json"] }`

```
impl Client {
    pub fn new(/*endpoint: Url*/) -> Result<Client> {
        Ok(Client {
            client: reqwest::ClientBuilder::new().build()?,
        })
    }
}
```

```rust
let res = self
    .client
    .post(url)
    .header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .header("Authorization", "Basic".to_owned() + &secret)
    .send
    .await?;
let data = res.json::<Response>().await?;
```

I'm not able to set the basic authorization header, and the code gives the error "Missing auth credentials".

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming your `secret` is encoded correctly, it looks to be missing a space after "Basic"

Comment: What have basic HTTP debugging tools, like netcat, shown that you are sending?

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for saving my debugging time. Not considering the space after "Basic" was the silly mistake which I never noticed while testing this. 
Works now.

Answer (score 8):

As suggested from above comments, added the missing space after "Basic" in the header, solved this problem.

```
let res = self
    .client
    .post(url)
    .header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .header("Authorization", "Basic ".to_owned() + &secret)
    .send()
    .await?;
```

Comment: `.send` should be called `.send()`.

Comment: should use the new-ish `basic_auth` builder instead. See example here: https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/discussions/1660